# Burninate [specific-answer] tag - questions are about Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [specific-answer](/questions/tagged/specific-answer) tag seems to contain questions only about Stack Overflow.
I did not go through all 108 questions, but quite a few of them.

I presume the tag is from when MSE was also MSO, to separate MSO questions from MSE ones.

The tag's excerpt (before the edit today) backs this up:

> Use this tag for questions on Meta that relate to a specific answer on
>   Stack Overflow.

(Edit: Note, the excerpt has just been changed "Stack Exchange")

---

If burnination is to proceed, how would it be done?
Just removing the tag from all questions in this case leaves off-topic questions.

Is it possible for someone to mass migrate?
Or, should we just close them all as "pertains to specific site"?

Comment: Wouldn't mass migrating them (if possible) cause in mass rep-loss? (to question askers and answers.) ***If*** something needs to happen, they should just be closed...

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I don't think that is the case, not sure. Doesn't migration only reset downvotes?

Comment: Not completely sure - but I *think*, once, when a question that I had answered was migrated, I lost any gained rep on that site, and gained it back on the other site. ***But*** there's no rep on SO Meta - so you won't be able to rearn the rep...

Comment: @James The "your reputation is safe" rules don't apply at all to migrated posts. When it's migrated to another site, you get all the reputation there, and lose all the reputation here (which for a Meta SE to site-specific Meta migration, involves just losing all the reputation).

Comment: @animuson Thanks for the confirmation. So what would be best here? Remove tag and close down questions? 108 is not many. Would take me alone no time at all.

Comment: Mass-migration sounds like the best option to me (after all, there are a bunch of questions; they're off-topic here but on-topic there…). If there isn't a mass-migration feature, then a few with the migration privilege will just have to do it by hand.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think this tag needs to be burninated. It is still useful to have a tag for questions that are about a specific answer, either here on MSE or else where on the network.

It is useful to have that indication, specially if the issue raised leads to a network-wide change in guidance / rules.

You are correct in your observation that most questions (and answers) only apply to a specific site, for historic reasons.

Most questions asked prior to the split are likely for Stack Overflow. There is a close reason for that. At best a tag clean-up could take place where questions and their answers will never make sense or be applicable to any community except Stack Overflow should be closed as off-topic / applies to a single site.

The tag itself can stay.